# Загрузка больших xml файлов в DataTable

Tags: c#, xml, ado.net, datatable

Пробую считывать XML файл в `DataTable` с помощью `ReadXml`.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("myxml.xml");
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table = ds.Tables[0];
```

На небольших файлах работает замечательно, но при загрузке файлов объемом более 1GB начинает выпадать ошибка

> "System.OutOfMemoryException" в mscorlib.dll

`DataTable` в последующем передаю для загрузки в БД, можно ли как нибудь считывать "порциями" записывать эту "порцию" в БД, очищать, потом опять считывать, и так до конца файла?

Comment: Данные такого объема нужно загружать не через DataSet (размещая его в памяти), а через bulk операции, которые предоставляет ваш провайдер баз данных.

Comment: Мне необходимо грузить в SQL Compact CE, там в стандартном нет такой загрузки, а сторонняя библиотека принимает `DataTable`, `List<T>`, [вот ссылка на библиотеку](https://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @e1s http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427381/import-large-xml-file-into-sql-server-ce

Comment: @andreycha это мой вопрос) просто думал на русском понятнее можно объяснить что требуется

Comment: @e1s ха :). Ну так вас там правильно поняли и правильно ответили: ручками файл парсить.

Comment: @e1s там есть пример использования IDataReader `private static void RunBulkCopy(SchemaType schemaType, bool keepNulls, bool keepKey, IDataReader reader)`, Сделайте обертку на XmlReader реализуя IDataReader. Тогда в памяти у вас должно быть не больше одной записи.

Comment: @MaLS не совсем вас понял

Comment: @e1s Пишешь класс, который наследует IDataReader. В нем создаёшь объект типа XmlReader. На каждый IDataReader.Read читаешь из XmlReader одну строку. Твой объект передаешь в SqlCeBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader reader). Так по записи загрузишь данные.

Comment: Смысла нет построчно читать и сразу строку записывать в БД, прелесть bulk загрузки в другом. Или я не понял вашу мысль

Comment: @e1s в данном случае в памяти будет размещаться данные только одной записи и вы не получите System.OutOfMemoryException при загрузке файлов > 1G. "Одна запись" - запись в таблице.

Comment: тогда можно просто писать запрос к БД и вставлять эту запись, зачем огород городить с bulk load ?

Comment: @e1s запрос подразумевает использование синтаксиса SQL, а это значит, что  подключается функционал парсинга запросов, что вызывает дополнительные тормоза. Bulk операция подразумевает прямое копирование данных в таблицу, с наименьшими потерями.

Comment: Какой парсинг? Открываем соединение через `SqlCeCommand` и потом в `CommandText` передаем запрос и все

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22547/discussion-between-mals-and-e1s).

Comment: @e1s в CommandText пишешь текст, и его нужно распарсить и преобразовать в нужные типы. А через ридер ты передаёшь int, он и записывает в базу int по битно.

Comment: @MaLS можно на примере?

Answer (score 1):

Переходите в x64 процесс. В противном случае грузите данные через bulk операции из файла.

Comment: Я думаю дело не в разрядности, просто очень много ресурсов требуется.

Answer (score 0):

Считывай файл через класс XmlReader 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx

```
XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader("file.xml");
while (textReader.Read())
{
    XmlNodeType nType = textReader.NodeType;
    if (nType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
    {
        // ...
    }
    if (nType == XmlNodeType.Comment)
    {
        // ...
    }
    if (nType == XmlNodeType.Attribute)
    {
        // ...
    }
    if (nType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        // ...                
    }
    if (nType == XmlNodeType.DocumentType)
    {
        // ...                
    }
}
```

Comment: Так там нет такого метода, просто в XML полно атрибутов и трудоемко создавать руками таблицу для хранения.

Comment: Попробуйте класс XmlDocument , он может считывать как реадера, так и с потока Stream.
Узлы и т.д. у него по свойствам получить сможете к примеру "ChildNodes Возвращает все дочерние узлы данного узла. (Унаследовано от XmlNode.)" Ну в общем вот направление вам :) Сам не занимался поэтому более подробно не подскажу.

Comment: Поток можно регулировать считыванием по байтам и т.д.... в общем есть где копаться.

Comment: ненужно ничего делать руками ( не могу коментить там из-за репутации низкой). Считайте данные в XmlDocument, или в переменную потоком изначально (чтоб память забить данными и не вызывать сбои в DLL), потом постепенно считаете в XMLDocument, из его свойств и т.д... составите XML схему, которую считаете классом DataTable.ReadXML и  DataTable.ReadXMLScheme (ну или как-то так пишется.

Comment: Так же на МСДН 
"Как создать поток XML-фрагментов с доступом к сведениям заголовка"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb387008.aspx
"Как выполнять потоковое преобразование больших XML-документов"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb387013.aspx

Comment: В том то и дело что если файл под 2 гига, когда его полностью считываешь, памяти не хватает

Comment: И не надо его считывать весь, поберегите ОЗУ для других задач параллельных. Конструкции повторяются ведь в XML. Определите блок конструкций и считывайте по блочно. Статьи указанные, вроде как рассказывают об этом. А вот подробные средства использования не могу знать :\ не пользовался и не требовалось.

Comment: Про msdn понятно, но вы видимо не до конца поняли вопрос, у меня в  теге допустим 40 атрибутов разных по типу, и в том случае как вы описали мне придется создавать поля в  `DataTable` вручную, для считанных данных

Comment: Возьмите DataTable с записями какими-либо и выполните WriteXML и WriteXMLScheme. Вы увидите что DataTable понимает XML схему. Считайте XML структуру из XMLDocument, преобразуйте ее в схему для DataTable (хитрыми путями конечно же), считайте ее с DataTable - вот вам и все поля и колоночки в таблице уже будут созданы "сами". И далее по накатанной вставляете данные :)
У XMLDocument есть всякие свойства и методы вытаскивания структуры XML содержимого, это и сделайте как схему для таблицы вашей, чтоб руками не создавать колонки.

Comment: Да не загрузит он xml объемом 2 гига в XMLDocument

Comment: Обновил ответ свой. Считывайте его по структурно, можно из потока. Определяйте что делать с этой структурой (может создать схему для DataTable ?), а потом уже прочитаете данные его. Считывайте структуру пока не поймете что все... дальше уже идет повтор  основной структуры. Постройте схему и считайте ее дата таблей и будет вам счастье - поблочное считывание данных, без загрузки в память (PS.. поток "FileStream" можно использовать - он указывает на связь с файлом последовательность байтов, а не забрасывает его весь в память)

Comment: так слишком муторно, у меня корневой тег, и в нем одинаковые теги с 30 атрибутами, по сути таблица двумерная

Comment: Ну что тебе можно сказать. Если муторно считать 1 тег, 30 его атрибутов и сделать схему из этого для DataTable. А потом нормально все быстренько прочитать в DataTable. 
Нуууу не знаю тогда в чем заключаются задачи программирования )))) Я думал решать подобные сложные ситуации. А иначе работайте ручками.

Comment: схемы xsd у меня есть готовые для этих xml

Comment: разбейте файл по частям. Заставьте того кто вам делает такой файл разбить его по частям. Или считывайте поблочно его через указанные множественные способы выше и не обязательно в DataTable. Можно сразу в DataSet считывать методом ReadXML(XMLReader), XMLReader создан через поток связи с файлом и считываются данные через метод поблочноко как в примере в ответе. (просто один фиг вам прийдется счиатть сколько-то, обработать и освободить память)

Comment: @e1s если есть схемы, тогда в чем проблема по блочно считать в DataTable методом ReadXml(параметр), если почитать какие параметры можно подставить в него, в т.ч. там можно использовать объекты умеющие читать файл XML блоками, а не полностью сразу весь. Главное не забывайте что по блочно, но не весь файл, а часть - обработали эту часть и освободили память.

Comment: Организуйте код следующим образом:
1) связались с файлом через поток или компонент, но без считывания его 2) начали цикл считывания файла блоком 3) как достигли конца 1 блока - вызываем функцию с передачей этого компонента в DataTable.ReadmXML(компонент), обработали инфу, убрали из памяти 4) вернулись к продолжению цикла (2)

Вроде вполне доступно написал. Учитывая все сказанное ))) удачи вам :)

Comment: нет там блоков , идет корневой тег, а в нем много тегов однотипных- <Object и тут 40 атрибутов>

Comment: Ну у вас же не 40 атрибутов 2 Гб занимают. А миллион их повторений. Вот и определите момент начала повторения.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [`BufferedStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.bufferedstream(v=vs.110).aspx) для загрузки:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("myxml.xml"))
{
    using (BufferedStream buffered = new BufferedStream(stream))
    {
        ds.ReadXml(buffered);
    }
}
```

Он считывает файл по чуть-чуть, а не целиком. Правда тут уже можно упереться в то, что загруженный `DataSet` будет занимать слишком много памяти. Но это уже другой вопрос :).

Comment: Так пробовал. Видимо `DataSet` разрастается и выпадает эта ошибка, можно как нибудь читать кусками?

Comment: @e1s тогда только руками: вычитываете данные из файла с помощью XmlReader, накапливаете определенное количество записей и балк инсертом отправляете в базу.